# When I execute selenium script, following it browser is being closed Automatically?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I am writing selenium script and It's working perfect but when code is running then my browser is automatically closed?

```
public  static void main(String args[])
{
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "./chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("URL");

        String email = "EMAil";
        String password = "123";

        int ELEMENT_WAIT_TIME_SEC = 60;
        WebDriverWait explicitWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, ELEMENT_WAIT_TIME_SEC);
        String locator = "//input[@type='email'][@aria-label='Email']";
        By findBy = By.xpath(locator);
        WebElement Login = explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(findBy));
        Login.click();
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('aria-invalid',true);", Login);
        Login.sendKeys(email);

        String plocator = "//input[@type='password'][@aria-label='Password']";
        By findByp = By.xpath(plocator);
        WebElement Password = explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(findByp));
        Password.click();
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('aria-invalid',true);", Password);
        Password.sendKeys(password);
}
```

Comment: Check your code.
driver.close() method is used for closing the browser.

Comment: @Hiten I am Not Writing Driver.close() in my code.

Comment: Are you receiving any exception?

Comment: Difficult for people to help without sharing your code here. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Anand No I am not receiving ANy Exception...

Comment: Could you share your written code?

Comment: @Anand Show Code

Comment: @Alan Show Code

Comment: @RushabhShah share complete code snippet here.

Comment: @GauravGenius  THIS MY COMPLETE CODE .........

Comment: There must be a line `driver.close()` somewhere in code, that's why it is closing browser.

Comment: @GauravGenius Ok Get it Point

Comment: @GauravGenius I get The Problem In One Function `driver.close()` is using ..

Comment: @Hiten  I get The Problem In One Function `driver.close()` is using..

Comment: just remove it and the browser will not automatically close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your code. May be you used `driver.close()` method to close the browser.
Just comment or delete that code and the browser will not close automatically.

Comment: it is Possible to  other Browser closed when code is run??

Comment: nope.
Its only close the open instance of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I got over this error by using the Code Runner extension of VS Code instead of manually running `node file-path`.

Works well.

Answer (score -1):

This is a case of browser version compatibility issue with chrome.  so  update your chromedriver.exe in sync with current version of Chrome browser.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18808548)

Comment: @Dez yeah I will take care of that, Thanks.